# Mobile phone authentication browser problem

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, browser

I'm using the mobile phone authentication function. In Chrome, Whale, and Samsung Internet browsers, callback is not made from a white window to an application after authentication. However, it runs normally in Edge and Naver browsers. Could it be a browser problem?

I checked the jsp file related to the authentication procedure and ran it with various kinds of browsers. I want to know if it's a source code problem or a browser problem.

source code
location.href = "biz.net://?param=" + encodeURI( JSON.stringfy(param));

Comment: Might be good to share some of your source code to help analyze the issue.  Sounds browser related, but need more specifics. Check out the [coc](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) to learn more about Stack Overflow and how to make the most of your questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.